# How to select the right admit/discharge window that has the transplant date fall under it

Tags: r, date, dataframe

Please see `dput()` below.

This is just the first 10 ids out of 500.

I need the admit and discharge dates that have the tx date fall within.
For example 1010008's tx date falls in admit17/dc17.

Each id can have up to 55 admit/discharge dates entered. Need the correct admit/discharge range for each id

Output should just include id, tx1, admit and discharge corresponding to tx1

`structure(list(id = c(1010001, 1010002, 1010004, 1010005, 1010006, 
1010007, 1010008, 1010009, 1010010, 1010013), tx1 = structure(c(1145318400, 
1211932800, 1235088000, 1119312000, 1244160000, 1096934400, 1154476800, 
1169424000, 1139270400, 1025481600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), admit1 = structure(c(1145232000, 1211760000, 
1174435200, 1059523200, 1044144000, 1096848000, 1058918400, 1155686400, 
1126656000, 1004140800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc1 = structure(c(1147219200, 1213660800, 1178668800, 1061510400, 
    1047340800, 1097798400, 1059523200, 1155945600, 1126915200, 
    1004918400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    admit2 = structure(c(NA, 1213833600, 1235001600, 1061683200, 
    1226534400, NA, 1062460800, 1167264000, 1139184000, 1005609600
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc2 = structure(c(NA, 
    1213920000, 1236643200, 1062460800, 1226707200, NA, 1062892800, 
    1167523200, 1140480000, 1006387200), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit3 = structure(c(NA, 1215129600, 
    1242172800, 1063756800, 1228953600, NA, 1067385600, 1167696000, 
    1140652800, 1006992000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc3 = structure(c(NA, 1215561600, 1242345600, 1063929600, 
    1229644800, NA, 1067904000, 1168128000, 1140912000, 1007164800
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit4 = structure(c(NA, 
    1217116800, NA, 1066435200, 1231113600, NA, 1069200000, 1169424000, 
    1144627200, 1007424000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc4 = structure(c(NA, 1217203200, NA, 1069200000, 1231372800, 
    NA, 1070409600, 1171843200, 1144800000, 1007596800), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit5 = structure(c(NA, 1218412800, 
    NA, 1070841600, 1244073600, NA, 1087689600, 1174348800, 1147132800, 
    1008720000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc5 = structure(c(NA, 1219881600, NA, 1070928000, 1245024000, 
    NA, 1087862400, 1174348800, 1147737600, 1008892800), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit6 = structure(c(NA, 1220572800, 
    NA, 1073433600, 1248739200, NA, 1089417600, 1177372800, 1148860800, 
    1012176000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc6 = structure(c(NA, 1222300800, NA, 1073520000, 1249948800, 
    NA, 1090627200, 1178409600, 1149033600, 1012262400), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit7 = structure(c(NA, 1223942400, 
    NA, 1089244800, 1250812800, NA, 1091059200, NA, 1291161600, 
    1025395200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc7 = structure(c(NA, 1224201600, NA, 1089331200, 1251244800, 
    NA, 1092268800, NA, 1291334400, 1027296000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit8 = structure(c(NA, 1225065600, 
    NA, 1089936000, 1317081600, NA, 1104796800, NA, 1319846400, 
    1029715200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc8 = structure(c(NA, 1225324800, NA, 1090368000, 1317945600, 
    NA, 1105920000, NA, 1320969600, 1029888000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit9 = structure(c(NA, 1231977600, 
    NA, 1098489600, NA, NA, 1109203200, NA, 1321228800, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc9 = structure(c(NA, 1232150400, 
    NA, 1099353600, NA, NA, 1109376000, NA, 1323043200, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit10 = structure(c(NA, 1247702400, 
    NA, 1115251200, NA, NA, 1113436800, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc10 = structure(c(NA, 1250121600, 
    NA, 1115510400, NA, NA, 1113868800, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit11 = structure(c(NA, 1250467200, 
    NA, 1119225600, NA, NA, 1119657600, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc11 = structure(c(NA, 1252022400, 
    NA, 1120521600, NA, NA, 1121126400, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit12 = structure(c(NA, 1253404800, 
    NA, 1136505600, NA, NA, 1132358400, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc12 = structure(c(NA, 1253750400, 
    NA, 1136592000, NA, NA, 1133395200, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit13 = structure(c(NA, 1255564800, 
    NA, 1141689600, NA, NA, 1136678400, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc13 = structure(c(NA, 1255651200, 
    NA, 1141862400, NA, NA, 1137542400, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit14 = structure(c(NA, 1256256000, 
    NA, 1228262400, NA, NA, 1137801600, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc14 = structure(c(NA, 1260748800, 
    NA, 1228435200, NA, NA, 1138060800, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit15 = structure(c(NA, NA, 
    NA, 1294272000, NA, NA, 1142208000, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc15 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 
    1294963200, NA, NA, 1142812800, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit16 = structure(c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1146096000, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc16 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1146182400, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit17 = structure(c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1154390400, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc17 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1157673600, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit18 = structure(c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1159228800, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc18 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1159315200, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit19 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), dc19 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    admit20 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc20 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), admit21 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc21 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit22 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), dc22 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    admit23 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc23 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), admit24 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc24 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit25 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), dc25 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    admit26 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc26 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), admit27 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc27 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit28 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), dc28 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    admit29 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc29 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), admit30 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc30 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit31 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), dc31 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    admit32 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc32 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), admit33 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc33 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit34 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), dc34 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    admit35 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc35 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), admit36 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc36 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit37 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), dc37 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    admit38 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc38 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), admit39 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc39 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit40 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), dc40 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    admit41 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc41 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), admit42 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc42 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit43 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), dc43 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    admit44 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc44 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), admit45 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc45 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit46 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), dc46 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    admit47 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc47 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), admit48 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc48 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit49 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), dc49 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    admit50 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc50 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), admit51 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc51 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit52 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), dc52 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    admit53 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dc53 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), admit54 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dc54 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), admit55 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), dc55 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`

Comment: Possible to include less data and fix the syntax error which prevents loading? Might be missing some parentheses?

Comment: @JonSpring does this edit help? I would really appreciate your help. I think I need a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  gather(col, val, -c(id, tx1)) %>%
  separate(col, c("type", "round"), "(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])") %>%
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>%
  spread(type, val) %>%
  filter(tx1 >= admit, tx1 <= dc)
```

First I gather all the columns except `id` and `tx1` to make it easier to work with the column names all together. Next, `tidyr::separate` is used here to split the column name into a text part ("type") and a number part ("round"). Then I filter out `NA` values, spread wide again, and filter for just tx dates that fall between the two others.

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
        id tx1                 round admit               dc                 
     <dbl> <dttm>              <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1 1010001 2006-04-18 00:00:00 1     2006-04-17 00:00:00 2006-05-10 00:00:00
 2 1010002 2008-05-28 00:00:00 1     2008-05-26 00:00:00 2008-06-17 00:00:00
 3 1010004 2009-02-20 00:00:00 2     2009-02-19 00:00:00 2009-03-10 00:00:00
 4 1010005 2005-06-21 00:00:00 11    2005-06-20 00:00:00 2005-07-05 00:00:00
 5 1010006 2009-06-05 00:00:00 5     2009-06-04 00:00:00 2009-06-15 00:00:00
 6 1010007 2004-10-05 00:00:00 1     2004-10-04 00:00:00 2004-10-15 00:00:00
 7 1010008 2006-08-02 00:00:00 17    2006-08-01 00:00:00 2006-09-08 00:00:00
 8 1010009 2007-01-22 00:00:00 4     2007-01-22 00:00:00 2007-02-19 00:00:00
 9 1010010 2006-02-07 00:00:00 2     2006-02-06 00:00:00 2006-02-21 00:00:00
10 1010013 2002-07-01 00:00:00 7     2002-06-30 00:00:00 2002-07-22 00:00:00
```